# Dynamically showing profile user name in 'from' email field using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

We're currently building a web-based application that allows users to sign up and create a profile. They can send emails from the platform using actionmailer but instead of showing a default 'no-reply' as the from field we need to show the sender's name. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: And what have you tried so far ? Can we see the code where you send the mail ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "From" header as seen on: [Action mailer options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration)

The from field of a mail is the name that is showed indicating the company or person it was sent by. The reply-to header is the mail it was sent from.

I can't help you more without seeing any code you are using.

Example code:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
default from: 'notifications@example.com'
default reply-to: 'notifications@example.com'

def welcome_email(user)
@user = user
@url  = 'http://example.com/login'
mail(to: @user.email,
     from: 'Name of sending user here <notifications@example.com>',
     subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site',
     template_path: 'notifications',
     template_name: 'another')
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.

Looks like it was a config issue. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is just a text-based protocol with no real verification. You can send an email with any `from` field.